# How to use ed25519 to encrypt/decrypt data?

Tags: c, encryption, encryption-asymmetric

Currently I am investigating https://github.com/orlp/ed25519 , and it has example for signing but how to use it for encrypting/decrypting data? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you want to send a message to Alice who has the public key `A`.

1. Generate a new ephemeral key pair `e`, `E`
2. Compute the shared DH secret between `e` and `A` using the `ed25519_key_exchange` function.
3. Use some kind of of KDF of that secret. In the simplest case a hash.
4. Use the value derived in step 3 as key in a symmetric algorithm

NaCl's `crypto_box` [works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663604/questions-about-the-nacl-crypto-library) almost like this. The main differences are that it uses Montgomery form public keys and uses HSalsa20 as hash in step 3.

Some people don't feel comfortable with using the [same keypair for signing and encryption](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3260/using-same-keypair-for-diffie-hellman-and-signing). Use at your own risk. If you don't need this key reuse, I'd recommend LibSodium as an alternative.

Answer (score 6):

You don't. ED25519 is a public-key signature system, not an encryption system. Trying to use it for a purpose it was not designed for is likely to introduce security vulnerabilities.

Comment: You cannot use Ed25519, but you can use Ed25519 public keys.

Comment: This answer may be valid but there's no references so no way for readers to know.